# Вывод уведомлений после отправки сообщений с формы (несколько форм)

Tags: jquery

Есть несколько форм с отправкой на email, как вывести статус отправки сообщения на каждой форме. Сейчас выводится только на одной, при отправке с другой формы статус выводится на первой.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            var formID = $(this).attr('id'); // Получение ID формы
            var formNm = $('#' + formID);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/inc/send.php', // Обработчик формы отправки
                data: formNm.serialize(),
    error:function(){$("#erconts").html("Произошла ошибка!");},
    /* если произойдет ошибка в элементе с id erconts выведется сообщение*/
    beforeSend: function() {
     $("#erconts").html("<p style='color: orangered;'>Отправляем данные...</p>");
    },
    success: function(result){
    /* В случае удачной обработки и отправки выполнится следующий код*/
      $('#erconts').html(result);
      checkThis();
    }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```html
//сюда выводится результат статуса отправки
<div id="erconts"></div>

<?php
/*ЕСЛИ ПИСЬМО ОТПРАВЛЕНО УСПЕШНО ВЫВОДИМ СООБЩЕНИЕ*/
    if ($send == "true")
    {
        echo "<p style='color: green;'>Ваше сообщение отправлено. Мы ответим вам в ближайшее время.\r\n</p>";
    }
    /*ЕСЛИ ПИСЬМО НЕ УДАЛОСЬ ОТПРАВИТЬ ВЫВОДИМ СООБЩЕНИЕ ОБ ОШИБКЕ*/
    else
    {
        echo "<p style='color: red;'>Не удалось отправить, попробуйте снова!</p>";
    }
?>
```

**UPD:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {
    let theForma = $(this);
    /*var formID = $(this).attr('id'); // Получение ID формы
    var formNm = $('#' + formID);*/
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/include/send.php', // Обработчик формы отправки
      data: theForma.serialize(),
      error: function() {
        $(".erconts").html("Произошла ошибка!");
      },
      /* если произойдет ошибка в элементе с id erconts выведется сообщение*/
      beforeSend: function() {
        $(".erconts").html("<p style='color: orangered;'>Отправляем данные...</p>");
      },
      success: function(result) {
        theForma.find('.erconts').html(result);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="mb-callback" class="form_modal_window" action="">
  .........
  <div class="erconts"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каждой форме заведите `<div class="erconts"></div>`.

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    let theForma = $(this);
```

В `success:` `theForma.find('.erconts').html(result);`

**upd:**

```
//html:
<form id="form1">
  <div class="erconts"></div>
  ...
</form>
...
<form id="formN">
  <div class="erconts"></div>
  ...
</form>
//ajax:
$('form').submit(function () {
  let theForma = $(this),
    erconts = theForma.find('.erconts');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/inc/send.php',
    data: theForma.serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
      erconts.html("<p style='color: orangered;'>Отправляем данные...</p>");
    },
    success: function(result) {
      erconts.html(result);
    },
    error: function() {
      erconts.html("Произошла ошибка!");
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Извините пожалуйста, не могли бы прям в самом коде отредактировать? Или отправить именно тот участок которые редактируется. У меня что то не получается.

Comment: Статус выводится, но зависает на "Отправляем данные". Сообщение приходит на e-mail. Полученный код, сейчас добавлю в вопрос.

Comment: немного обновил ответ